# $\{ a + b\sqrt{2} | a,b\in \Bbb Z\}$ is a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\{ a + b\sqrt{2} | a,b\in \Bbb Z\}$ I have that this is a ring, but I do not see how it is an abelian group under addition, since $a + b\sqrt{2}$ does not equal $b\sqrt{2}+ a $ since we are in the intergers.

Comment: Hi! I don't understand the reason why $a+b\sqrt 2$ and $b\sqrt 2+a$ is not the same number. Can you express more precisily your doubt?

Comment: ok yes that made sense. If you look at the answer as a whole, not that $a$ is not equal to $b\sqrt(2)$

Comment: Called $R=\{a+b\sqrt 2 \ | \ a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$ the sum operation in this set is the sum operation as a subset of $\mathbb R$. So $R$ is an abelian group.

Comment: How did you defined the sum operation on your given set in the first place?

Comment: As the "usual addition"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly $a,b,\sqrt2\in\Bbb R$ and $b\sqrt2\in\Bbb R$. The subset $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]:=\{a+b\sqrt2~\mid~a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$ is *closed* under $\Bbb R$-addition. That is, for every $x=a+b\sqrt2,y=c+d\sqrt2\in R$ we have $x+y\in R$. Indeed, oberserve that
$$x+y=(a+b\sqrt2)+(c+d\sqrt2)=(a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt2=e+f\sqrt2\in R$$
The aforegoing reordering takes place in $\Bbb R$ and we are free to use any related properties of $\Bbb R$-addition and $\Bbb R$-multiplication. Then we *define* $R$-addition by 
$$x\oplus y=(a+b\sqrt2)\oplus(c+d\sqrt2):=(a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt2$$
Here $a+c$ and $b+d$ refer to $\Bbb Z$-addition. As shown before, this subset is closed under this operation by jumping out of $R$ for a moment.  Now we can go on and examine all properties an abelian group has to fulfill by admitting that $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is an abelian group.

In fact, $R$ is a *subgroup* of $\Bbb R$, that is an abelian group by itself. $0\in R$, so $R$ is non-empty and if $x=a+b\sqrt2,y=c+d\sqrt2\in R$ it follows that
$$x+(-y)=(a+b\sqrt2)-(c+d\sqrt2)=(a-c)+(b-d)\sqrt2\in R$$
By the subgroup test is follows that $R$ is, indeed, a subgroup of $R$ with respect to $\Bbb R$-addition.